# Why Do I Get This Error Message When I Send A Job to The Render Network?

Tags: rendering, network

I'm trying to use the render network on a Windows 8.1 PC with a local network, but I keep on receiving the error message shown in red when I select "Animation on Network".

Just to explain what I have done, I set up my master and 1 slave which is ready to go. Then I assigned a client instance with an assigned directory path to send the temp files and the rendered files. I had saved the file before clicking **Animation on Network**.

Could someone please explain this error message and how can I fix it?

[image]
[image]
![Blender Network Render Error Message][3]

![enter image description here][4]

Comment: Could this be caused by firewall settings? You should add which OS you use, and whether this happens in your local network.

Comment: I use a Windows 8.1 PC and I am using a local network. What firewall settings should I adjust? or do I need to turn it off?

Comment: I think Windows will popup a dialog where the admin should allow network access. You see a timeout, that means (probably) that the host is reached and it has successfully connected to the port but then there is no response. I used this configuration one time and had also issues. What does the web-interface display in your browser (http://localhost:8000/html/newui) ?

Comment: It States http:/myIPaddress:8000/html